# Groovy - characters loss with stream.getText

Tags: groovy

I have this Groovy script that I'm testing:

```
InputStream is = awsS3Stream.getObjectContent();
def lines = is.getText("UTF-8");
println "lines:"+lines;
Pattern pattern = ~/type\"\:\"[A-Z][a-z]*\"/;
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lines);
...
```

I noticed that depending on the size of the awsS3Stream object, variable lines may not have all of the text - the end of it is missing. I was hoping that  using StringBuffer instead of String would solve the issue, but it did not. I hope someone may know a Groovy based solution to it as I'm not terribly familiar with Groovy... much appreciate your time. 
 
P.S The issues I'm seeing is not related to the pattern - I don't need pattern there to see that the variable lines doesn't always have all of the data.

Comment: tbh, not sure it's related to groovy. `getText` just reads all the stream

Comment: Not sure why that would be a problem but have you tried using `is.eachLine()` or `is.filterLine()`?  Take a look at GDK InputStream API.  http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html

Comment: @todd-w-crone  I tried using readLine with BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));  But had the same result.

Comment: I don't guess you could send me a copy of the file that is causing loss of data for `is.text`?  I'm really curious now.

Comment: @todd-w-crone yes, I could. I'm not sure what would be the best way. Could you post an email address  I could send it to?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match alphabetic strings with just one initial uppercase letter?  If not, the problem is with your regexp.  To match camel case strings with any number of capital letters, use this:

```
Pattern pattern = ~/type\"\:\"[A-Za-z]*\"/;
```

Comment: Yes, only one initial letter for now. I'll have to test later with Strings like NodeTest, where i'll need to do more for the pattern but for now I'm getting what I need out of it.

Comment: I added more to my initial message to clarify the pattern is not where I'm seeing the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the data going into s3, not how I retrieve it.